# How to ignore spelling and grammar for certain text styles in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, spell-check, ignore, grammar

Is there a way to ignore spelling and grammar for certain text styles in Word 2007?

Some of the stuff I'm writing is pre-formatted text `that looks like this` and usually has stuff like `if (str.length() != 3)` which will give me the squiggly lines on misspelled words like the `str` in there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Quick Styles will help you here.

First, select the text for which you want to ignore spelling in your document. Right click and select `Styles > Save selection as a new Quick Style`. Then click on `Modify` and a new window will open named "Create new style from Formatting". Set your font type, font size etc. and then click on the `Format` button which stands on the lower left corner of the window. Select `Language` option and check "Do not check spelling or grammar" option. Click `OK`, and `OK` again. Now you have a style which wil not check spelling or grammar for the font style you determined.

Comment: I had to close open to remove the underlining. Still works a treat.