# Word 2010,Add bunch of words in paragraph in one step to spell checker dictionary?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, spell-check

I have to create Documents in about my project that is written in about Android.I use `Word 2010` and I copy some lines of my code into the Word doc then I add my descriptions.My problem is huge number of error of spell checker of Word that arises in each paragraph(lines that I paste them from my code into Word).For example it may be used `setSpan`,`removeSpan` and ... in my codes and spell checker show red underline under all of them.You can see huge number of errors in a few lines that I paste them:

[image]

Is there a way to add all spell errors to word dictionary at once for selected area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know these probably don't solve your issue in the way you described but I would check out things like these posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514283/how-to-avoid-spell-checking-of-source-code-in-ms-word
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387453/best-way-to-show-code-snippets-in-word
- [How to ignore spelling and grammar for certain text styles in Word 2007](https://superuser.com/questions/148055/how-to-ignore-spelling-and-grammar-for-certain-text-styles-in-word-2007)

Comment: No problem, good luck!