# Can Spelling and Grammar be disabled for part of a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2000, microsoft-word-97

My document contains two large sections. One is the main body of the document (written with `Arial` font) and the other is an appendix with source code (written with `Courier New` font).

Spelling and Grammar checking is useful in the main body but goes crazy on the source code section with lines like `while (row < settingsRowsCols->totalRows)`. I'd like to stop spelling / grammar checking on the entire source code section, or insert some field code to tell Word only to perform checking on parts of the document.

This [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/148055/how-to-ignore-spelling-and-grammar-for-certain-text-styles-in-word-2007) appears to have a satisfactory answer for Word 2007. Can something similar be done on older versions of Word, in particular Word 97 or Word 2000?

Note: This [Office support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/The-spelling-and-grammar-checker-isn-t-working-as-expected-36a52ba2-147c-4adf-a4d6-6f40fa747be1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) only mentions this kind of feature back to Word 2007. Office 97, 2000 and 2003 are no longer supported by Microsoft who tend to scrub useful information about older products from their support pages to encourage upgrades. It is possible the feature to turn off checking on parts of the document was only introduced in 2007.

Comment: The best I've been able to do with Word 97 is to put the code in a separate document, which is inserted into the main body. Inserted documents are not spell/grammar-checked in the main document, but they need to be edited in a separate Window. This might work for you, where all your code is in an appendix, but would not be practical where code is interspersed throughout the text.

Comment: That might work because most of the code is in an appendix! Are you referring to the `Insert > File...` option? Never used that tpion before. If you make changes to the child "Code" document, does it automatically update the main document or do you need to re-insert the child document?

Comment: I used `Insert` -> `Object` -> `Create from File`. If I clicked on the insertion it opened the document in a separate window. As far as I could see, any change appeared in the main document, so I assume Word sets up a link, rather than copying the contents of the inserted document.